# I want to sort dataframe by duplicates in one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have df from employers like this:

```
data = {'Jobs':['Python-Dev', 'Data Scientist', 'Python-Dev', 'Data Scientist', 'Java-Dev', 'Programmer'], 
    'Skill_01':['python', 'pandas', 'python', 'keras', 'java', 'C++'],
    'Skill_02':['beautifulsoup', 'opencv', 'javascript', 'opencv', 'MySQL', 'nan'],
    'Skill_03':['english B2', 'tensorflow', 'flask', 'nan', 'PostgreSQL', 'nan'],
    'Skill_04':['nan', 'numpy', 'django', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan'],
    'Skill_05':['nan', 'nan', 'sql', 'nan', 'nan', 'nan'],}
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

Different skill requirements because employers are different. Then i want to sort dataframe by duplicates in one column with appending skills-columns.

I need output like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) first to remove those missing values and then [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df = data_df.replace('nan',np.nan).set_index('Jobs').stack().reset_index()
c = df.groupby('Jobs').level_1.cumcount()
df = df.pivot_table(index='Jobs', columns=c, values=0, aggfunc='first').reset_index()
df['DuplciateJobs'] = df.Jobs.map(data_df.Jobs.value_counts())

print(df)
             Jobs       0              1           2       3           4  \
0  Data Scientist  pandas         opencv  tensorflow   numpy       keras   
1        Java-Dev    java          MySQL  PostgreSQL     NaN         NaN   
2      Programmer     C++            NaN         NaN     NaN         NaN   
3      Python-Dev  python  beautifulsoup  english B2  python  javascript   

        5       6    7  DuplciateJobs  
0  opencv     NaN  NaN              2  
1     NaN     NaN  NaN              1  
2     NaN     NaN  NaN              1  
3   flask  django  sql              2
```